# How to access child route params in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to access route params from a parent component. I know that using withRouter you only have access to nearest parent route params. Therefore, what is the solution for access the current route params in a parent component? I am using react router v5.

Comment: Can you provide us with some context how you want to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question correctly, you can capture the current match props in childs componentDidUpdate and pass it up as prop. something like this:
child.js:

```js
//skipping the class definition and render method
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    // when location gets updated in child component
    if(JSON.stringify(this.props.match)!=JSON.stringify(prevProps.match)){
        //match.id or whatever param you need in parent component
        this.props.cb(this.props.match.id);
    }
}
```

parent:

```js
handleParamUpdate(id){
    console.log(id)
}
render(){
    return(
        <Child cb={this.handleParamUpdate}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly meant this. and it seems OK. But I thought may be there is a better solution to this. Thank you.